# Folder-level Acrobat X script to populate form fields

Tags: javascript, acrobat, populate

Hey guys I'm working on a folder-level script in Acrobat X and my intention is to fill in form fields automatically from an xml file I created previously.  My mom has to repetitively fill out this same form with very similar data for her work so I'm trying to help her out.  I'm not lazy or retarded either - I've been working on this for a solid month non-stop... I didn't even know javascript before I started.  So I'm kind of at the end of my journey with this project and I'm stuck trying to figure out how to create the privileged, folder-level function necessary to populate these fields programatically.

Here's my current plan... I go into the pdf and create a new bookmark and on this bookmark I attach a script that calls a privileged function.  The script runs but it's not recognizing the privileged function I wrote and saved in the app-level javascript folder.  This is the script:

```
myTrustedPopulate = app.trustedFunction( function (doc)
{
xmlFilePath = "C:\java\scraping\equator";

stmData = util.readFileIntoStream(xmlFilePath);

var address = oDoc.getField("address_1");

address.value = xmlData.cl.address.text();
return;
});
```

And this is the script I attached to the bookmark:

```
myTrustedPopulate(doc);
```

Listen, I'm not looking for anyone to do the work for me.  Even if you could just point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually I think I've just about solved it...  I'll update this when after I try a few things I'm reading in the api reference.

Comment: Okay I made a lot of progress but I'm stuck on another problem with parsing the xml.  Here's the link to the new question with the updated code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783800/parsing-an-xml-file-in-acrobat-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The cPath method is incorrect.  It should be:

"/C/java/scraping/equator"

You must also use the xml file extension in the path.